# Sum of a column of expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to take the value from a group of figures calculated by

```
=sum((Code.QRSupport.StockAtDate(Fields!PluNo.Value, Fields!SiteNo.Value, Parameters!SessionDateFrom.Value))+(Fields!DeliveryQty.Value)+(Fields!TransferInQty.Value)+(Fields!TransferOutQty.Value)+(Fields!WasteQty.Value)+(Fields!ReturnsQty.Value)+(Fields!CorrectionQty.Value)+(Fields!StockCheckQty.Value)+(Fields!SaleQty.Value))*(Sum(Fields!OuterCost.Value/Fields!OuterSize.Value))
```

This will then be totalled at the end of the group like below.
[image]

No matter what i try i do not get the total of them, it seems to take the total of the group price and the group calculated close.

Any help will be appreciated. Im about to throw my laptop out the window!!
[image]

Comment: Added the tags it’s using report builder 3

Comment: Have you tried just summing the textbox? So, if your current expression is in a textbox called `CalcValue` then just use `=SUM(ReportItems!CalcValue.Value)`

Comment: Yea no luck unfortunately 

The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox124.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data (that I don't have to retype) and you custom code function it's hard to test but this should be along the right lines.

This assumes you have a rowgroup (it looks like you group on description?). You ned to replace the two `myRowGroup` references with the name of your rowgroup, it is case sensitive and must be enclosed in quotes.

```
=
SUM(
    sum(
        (
            Code.QRSupport.StockAtDate(Fields!PluNo.Value, Fields!SiteNo.Value, Parameters!SessionDateFrom.Value)
        )
        +(Fields!DeliveryQty.Value)
        +(Fields!TransferInQty.Value)
        +(Fields!TransferOutQty.Value)
        +(Fields!WasteQty.Value)
        +(Fields!ReturnsQty.Value)
        +(Fields!CorrectionQty.Value)
        +(Fields!StockCheckQty.Value)
        +(Fields!SaleQty.Value)
        , "myRowGroup")
        *
        (Sum(Fields!OuterCost.Value/Fields!OuterSize.Value, "myRowGroup"))
)
```

All we are doing here is taking you group level expression, specifying the scope to be the group level and then sum the results.